# merge datasets with loop R

Tags: r, merge

I have a list of 72 datasets loaded in the Global Environment. Each dataset contains a column called uniqueID filled with unique identifiers.
I want to merge each dataset with another dataset based on these unique identifiers (i.e. uniqueID).

I can do the following on a dataset by dataset basis:

```
dataset1<-merge(dataset1,tomerge,by="uniqueID",all.x=TRUE)
```

However as I have many datasets I would like to do this using a loop.

Here is what I have tried:

```
  dflist<-Filter(is.data.frame, as.list(.GlobalEnv))
  dflist<-function(df,x){df<-merge(df,tomerge,all.x=TRUE)}
```

Here is an example of dataset1 and tomerge that I am trying to merge:

```
dput(dataset1[1:2, ])
structure(list(id = c(1, 2), geometry = structure(list(structure(c(12.7709873378252, 
                                                                 -2.34780379794057), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(13.7404727250738, 
                                                                                                                                   -3.08397066598979), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                    "sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 12.7709873378252, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              ymin = -2.08397066598979, xmax = 13.7404727250738, ymax = -1.34780379794057
                                                                                                                                                                                                    ), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(epsg = NA_integer_, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             proj4string = NA_character_), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L), 
             uniqueID = c("id_1_v12_3", "id_2_v13_3")), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(id = NA_integer_, 
                                                                                                 shapefile = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", 
                                                                                                                                      "identity"), class = "factor"), row.names = 1:2, class = c("sf", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                 "data.frame"))
```

````
dput(tomerge[1:2, 2:3 ])
structure(list(uniqueID = c("id_1_v12_3", "id_2_v13_2"), todigit = c("y", 
                                                                                "y")), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                                                                )) ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `lapply` to loop over the `list` of data.frame and `merge` with the 'tomerge' data

```
dfmergelist <- lapply(dflist, function(x)
      merge(x, tomerge, by = "uniqueID", all.x = TRUE))
```

where

```
dflist <- Filter(is.data.frame, mget(ls()))
```